# Unable to export Amcharts in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, export, amcharts

I am trying to [export amcharts to image](http://blog.amcharts.com/2012/09/exporting-javascript-charts-maps-as.html). The provided [example](http://jsfiddle.net/maertz/qf5m3/) works in Chrome and FF, but not in IE (I tried 8 and 9).

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: What exceptions, if any, occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tetra1337 found the [answer](http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=38558#p38558). It is necessary to replace *toString.call()* by *String()*.

See the [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qf5m3/111/).